Projectile motion - mathematical physics
$A$ is at $(0,0)$, $B$ is at $(200,0)$. $B$ is going to do a motion of free fall ($g$ is $10$), $A$'s speed is constant $60$ and always towards $B$.

My question is:

Can $A$ hit $B$?
What is the equation between $A'x$ and $A'y$?

Below are my solution:
$$
y'=\frac{5t^2-y}{200-x}
$$
Because A's speed is constant 60,Thus
$$
t=\frac{\int_{0}^{x}\sqrt{1+y'^2} dx}{60}
$$
We can get
$$
y'=\frac{5[\frac{\int_{0}^{x}\sqrt{1+y'^2} dx}{60}]^2-y}{200-x}
$$
Now the problem is solving the last equation to get A's moving trajectory.How to solve it?

A's speed is horizontal not towards B.

Furthermore A is also falling with acceleration g, so eventually it will meet B

not horizontal, A's speed is always towards B

imagining that A's speed is always 60 and towards B,

Does gravity not act on A?

Assumed that gravity not act on A.

You could examine time subintervals like $[0,2],[2,4],[4,6]$ and underestimate the average horizontal and vertical speed of $A$ over these intervals. I think with these numbers, it would show that $A$ will collide with $B$ even before time $t=4$. (Note that you need collision to happen before time $t=6$, or else for sure $B$ has accelerated too much for $A$ to catch it.)

@John, are you sure that the problem statement is that A's speed is constant and that it's velocity vector always points to B (like if it was a guided missile)? Because if yes, then the problem is a nightmare, if possible at all, to resolve in a closed form, as xeixx showed below. But there is a classic problem in Physics 1 where if you launch a projectile (A) directly at a target (B) and the target starts to fall at the same time, the projectile will ALWAYS hit the target for any initial positions of A and B and any initial speed of A. And this is easily solvable with a nice closed form.

@Gabriel Brown,Yes,A's speed is constant and it's velocity vector always points to B.It seems difficult to be solved.

Ah yes, the classic pursuit curve problem.

Yes, $A$ will eventually hit $B$.

I don't think any justifications is required for this, as it is quite self-evident heuristically.

Equations of $A'x$ and $A'y$:

$A$ starts initially at $(0,0)$ and is moving at a speed of $60\text{m/s}$, always directed to $B$. $B$ starts at $(200,0)$ and falls vertically. Its position at any time $t$ is $(200,5t^2)$ (derived from the formula for vertical displacement) where $g=10\text{m/s}^2$.
Let's first find the equations that govern $A$'s position as a function of time; $x_A(t)$ and $y_A(t)$.
As at any time $A$ is moving with speed $60\text{m\s}$ directed to $B$, the distance between $A$ and $B$ at time $t$ is;
$$d(t)=\sqrt{(200-x_A(t))^2+(5t^2-y_A(t))^2}$$
The motion of $A$ can be split into horizontal and vertical components, being
$$v_{Ax}=\frac{dx_A}{dt}$$
$$v_{Ay}=\frac{dy_A}{dt}$$
Since $A$'s velocity is always to $B$, the velocity components can be written as proportions of the total velocity in the direction of $B$. This gives us the following relations
$$\frac{dx_A}{dt}=60\cdot\frac{200-x_A(t)}{d(t)}$$
$$\frac{dy_A}{dt}=60\cdot\frac{5t^2-y_A(t)}{d(t)}$$
Now meaning we have two coupled differential equations that describe $A$'s motion;
$$\boxed{\frac{dx_A}{dt}=60\cdot\frac{200-x_A(t)}{\sqrt{(200-x_A(t))^2+(5t^2-y_A(t))^2}}}$$
$$\boxed{\frac{dy_A}{dt}=60\cdot\frac{5t^2-y_A(t)}{\sqrt{(200-x_A(t))^2+(5t^2-y_A(t))^2}}}$$
These are first order differential equations where time derivatives of $x_A(t)$ and $y_A(t)$ are expressed in terms of the current positions $x_A(t)$ and $y_A(t)$ and time $t$.
Since these equations are coupled and nonlinear, they are not easily solvable by hand using elementary functions. Thus I think this is the furthest we can go. Moreover, consider that this doesn't account for acceleration, nor is $A$ bounded by gravity.


Do you mean that we can't get the relational experssion of x and y by solving these two equations using hand?

I think the answer of question 1 is not right, If A can't catch up B before B's velocity reach 60 then A will never hit B.

I assumed that $B$'s velocity would not accelerate? And that $A$ remained constant at $60\text{m/s}$. Sorry but if you reclarify I can give a better answer.

Moreover, yes. They are extremely hard to solve by hand (in my opinion) but maybe another user can solve them.

@keixx , you did assume that B would accelerate at $10 m/s^2$ down (direction that you are taking as y+ since you stated B's position as $(200, 5t^2)$, not $(200, -5t^2)$. So if you assume that A's speed remains constant (which is what I understand too), how can you say that it is obvious that A will hit B eventually? Because John is right: If they didn't meet by when B reaches 60 m/s, they never will.

Yes, I recognize that $B$ must be hit by $A$ before $6$ seconds (where $B$ has fallen $210$m). I erroneously assumed that $B$ was constant at $10$m/s which was a big error. I'll try reattempt the question soon when I have free time, thanks!

Calling $\vec v_1, \vec v_2$ the projectile and the target absolute velocities respectively, the relative velocity between then in the projectile frame, can be equated as
$$
\frac{d}{dt}(r(t)(\cos(\theta(t)),\sin(\theta(t))) = \vec v_2 - \vec v_1
$$
where $r(t)$ is the distance between the projectile and the target.
Here $\vec v_2 = (0, -g t)$ and $\vec v_1 = (\cos(\theta(t)),\sin(\theta(t)))v_0$ with $v_0$ given. Developing we arrive at the movement equations
$$
\cases{
r' = -g t \sin\theta - v_0\\
\theta' = -\frac{g t}{r}\cos\theta\\
x_p' = \cos\theta v_0\\
y_p' = \sin\theta v_0
}
$$
where $(x_p,y_p)$ is the projectile position. This ode should be solved with initial conditions $r_0 = 200,\theta_0 = 0,x_p(0) = 0, y_p(0) = 0$. Follows the relative distance plot $(r(t))$ with the impact at $t = 4.0628$[s].

Also a plot showing the paths of projectile (blue) and target (dashed,red).

